# htaccess redirect with sub-domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a domain example.com and in .htaccess, I am forwarding non-www to www address using below code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now I created a subdomain test.example.com and because of above rule, its going to http://www.test.example.com, so I thought to write it's own htaccess file to redirect www to non-www. So in the subdomain root, I have .htaccess file with below rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's not working and going in a **redirect loop**, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very easy solution for this problem.

My main site document root was `/home/example/public_html` and subdomain document root was `/home/example/public_html/test`.

I just changed the document root of subdomain to `/home/example/test` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the ! and the escapes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Didn't worked, still the same issue. I did changes only in the subdomain htaccess file

Comment: Are you sure it's actually hitting that file? Vhost issue maybe?

Comment: its hitting that, as soon I remove htaccess rule, it starts working and forwarding to www.test.example.com

Comment: But if it forwards to www.test.example.com, that would mean it's hitting the top one.

Comment: That's the problem, its going into loop because both the rules are working. As soon as I remove the subdomain forward rule, it works fine. Not sure how to avoid the top htaccess to work.

Comment: If you have two separate vhosts that point to two separate document roots, it should always avoid the top one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 rules. Just keep this rule in main .htaccess for your main domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Now `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$` condition will only impact main domain leaving your sub domain untouched.

Comment: Changing DocumentRoot will sure avoid impacting sub domains but you can still keep this rule in case you create some CNAME, alias domains in future.